# Change checkout submit button text for a specific payment method in WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I need to change the `order_button_text` for a specific payment gateway (COD in this case).

I could only get it to change globally (for all payment gateways) using:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'multiple_orders_text' );
function woo_custom_order_button_text() {
    return __( 'Request Shipping Quote', 'woocommerce' );
}
```

But have found that if I add the line

```
$this->order_button_text  = __( 'Request a Quote', 'woocommerce' );
```

to the `setup_properties()` method in `woocommerce/includes/gateways/cod/class-wc-gateway-cod.php` it does work.

However this is clearly bad practice as I'm hacking a core plugin file.

How can I achieve this without hacking a woocommerce core file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways' );
function woocommerce_available_payment_gateways( $available_gateways ) {
    if (! is_checkout() ) return $available_gateways;  // stop doing anything if we're not on checkout page.
    if (array_key_exists('paypal',$available_gateways)) {
        // Gateway ID for Paypal is 'paypal'. 
         $available_gateways['paypal']->order_button_text = __( 'Request a Quote', 'woocommerce' );
    }
    return $available_gateways;
}
```

[image: reigelgallarde.me]
This code example is for paypal. For reference of the gateway IDs, please check **WooCoomerce** > **Settings** > **Checkout** > **Gateway display order**

[image: reigelgallarde.me]

Comment: Thanks loads, that worked! Made a small tweak to check the array key exists first, otherwise an errror is thrown:

`if (array_key_exists("paypal",$available_gateways)) { $available_gateways['paypal']->order_button_text = __( 'Pay with Paypal', 'woocommerce' ); }`

Hace chosen as accepted answer as I like that this solution works before the render cycle.

Comment: As a side question, where do you learn about these solutions?  It's particularly with woocommerce that I seem to ended up scrabbling around for solutions in a somewhat undirected manner.

Comment: To be honest you can't find more help than reading the source code... tracing what this and that does. For your problem as an example, I started with looking for `order_button_text` and found it on the payment gateway class. I then look for  the code where the payment gateway is being called, ended up on the function `woocommerce_checkout_payment`. Then saw that I can alter the variable `$available_gateways` there. I then look for the nearest filter I could find. Ended up `woocommerce_available_payment_gateways`.

Comment: PHP knowledge is a must too.. Because it's hard tracing code if you don't know how it works.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful to know how you found the solution.  Woo documentation isn't great. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

*2023 Summer Update*

Has WooCommerce has changed, better use the following linked answer instead: 
[Change WooCommerce submit checkout button text based on the chosen payment method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76731878/change-woocommerce-submit-checkout-button-text-based-on-the-chosen-payment-metho/76732687#76732687)

---

*Updated*

Here it is the proper way to do it, using **`woocommerce_review_order_before_payment`** action hook with a custom function hooked in, using mainly jQuery *(because it's a client side live event)*:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_init', 'customizing_checkout_button' );
function customizing_checkout_button(){
    $text1  = __( 'Place order', 'woocommerce' );
    $text2  = __( 'Request a Quote', 'woocommerce' );

    wc_enqueue_js("var payment = 'input[name=payment_method]',
    pChecked = payment+':checked', placeOrder = '#place_order';
         
    function changeButtonPaymentText() {
        if($(pChecked).val() == 'cod' ) {
            $(placeOrder).html('{$text2}');
        } else {
            $(placeOrder).html('{$text1}');
        }
    }
    changeButtonPaymentText();
    $( 'form.checkout' ).on( 'change', payment, function() {
        changeButtonPaymentText();
    });");
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works on last WooCommerce version (7.9)

Useful: [How to get the ID of a payment method in Woocommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76605181/how-to-get-the-id-of-a-payment-method-in-woocommerce/76606648#76606648)

Answer (score -1):

Easy solution, try to add the following code in your theme's `function.php` file.

```
/**
 * @snippet       Change checkout order button text
 * @package       WooCommerce
 */
function change_checkout_order_button_text() {
    return __( 'Complete Order', 'woocommerce' ); 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_button_text', 'change_checkout_order_button_text' );
```