# Change order reserved stock time for specific payment method in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, product, stock, orders

I am using WooCommerce for selling some digital products. Due to the natural of our business, we do not want the item stock to go lower than 0 (-1, -2, etc.)

We are currently accepting different payment methods, including Cryptocurrency and Stripe. As the transaction speed of Crypto is low, sometimes takes up to 1 hour, so we are facing issue like this:

1. When a user (User A) purchase an item and pay with Crypto, the item stock gets hold (going from 1 to 0). As the blockchain is slow, it takes 2 hours to complete the payment. Since it's so slow, the item stock goes back from 0 to 1.
2. While the blockchain payment is still pending, a different user (User B) comes to buy the same product. At this time, the item is not being held anymore. Thus, this user gets the product. Item stock goes from 1 to 0.
3. The blockchain payment is finally confirmed. Woocommerce also gives the product to this user. Item stock goes from 0 to -1.

So 2 users get the same product.

How to prevent this issue?

I haven't found any solution yet.

Comment: What is the payment ID for this Cryptocurrency payment option (see [How to get the ID of a payment method in Woocommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76606648/3730754))

Comment: It's coinbase and coinpayments. Thank you a ton!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should change the time to hold the stock *(60 minutes by default)* for an order passed with a specific payment method *(untested)*.

See [How to get the ID of a payment method in WooCommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76606648/3730754).

Below, inside the function, you will define the desired payment method(s) ID(s) *(for your cryptocurrency payment option(s))* and the desired time in minutes to hold the stock:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_created', 'wc_reserve_stock_for_crypto', 5 );
function wc_reserve_stock_for_crypto( $order ) {
    // HERE below define the desired payment ID(s)
    $targeted_payment_ids = array('coinbase', 'coinpayments'); 
    // HERE below define the time in minutes to hold stock
    $hold_stock_minutes   = 150; 

    if ( in_array( $order->get_payment_method(), $targeted_payment_ids ) ) {
        // Remove the default functionality to hold stock for 60 minutes
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_created', 'wc_reserve_stock_for_order' );

        if ( ! apply_filters( 'woocommerce_hold_stock_for_checkout', wc_string_to_bool( get_option( 'woocommerce_manage_stock', 'yes' ) ) ) ) {
            return;
        }

        $order = $order instanceof WC_Order ? $order : wc_get_order( $order );

        if ( $order ) {
            // Add back the functionality with a custom delay to hold the stock
            ( new \Automattic\WooCommerce\Checkout\Helpers\ReserveStock() )->reserve_stock_for_order( $order, $hold_stock_minutes );
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.